# Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid in Google Big Query

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api

i had problem with google bigquery when i put dataframe by pandas and they give authorize url
when i click url .they block and show

Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid

```
df_and_route_cost.to_gbq(destination_table='sutiwattdashboardforflash.cost_flash',
                  project_id='flash_cost_route',
                  if_exists='replace')
```

Authorize url

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=725825577420-unm2gnkiprugilg743tkbig250f4sfsj.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpydata-google-auth.readthedocs.io%2Fen%2Flatest%2Foauth.html&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&state=s2LDhubRx7tARxhpiX4psOrbwfP0Om&access_type=offline

i want my dataframe send to google bigquery by api